# TeamCity API method to get Slack notification info

Tags: api, notifications, teamcity, slack

Im trying to list my TeamCity builds in my own site with the TeamCity API to create dashboard. One feature I need is to notify the right person. To do so I set in the build setting the right Slack channel as the notification configuration.
My question is, is there a way to get this info from the TeamCity API? And if not, is there any way to get this info from other place?

Thanks!

**UPD**: This is how the Slack notifier is configured:

[On this picture we choose the 'Slack' option in menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mx9O.png)

[Here in bottom option we set the slack channel for this build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnWSe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get get the information about `Build features` via TeamCity REST API and the features will in turn contain information about configured Slack notifiers.

Example of a response for a `GET` request to `https://<serverUrl>/app/rest/buildTypes/id:MY_BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<buildType id="MY_BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID" name="Build configuration name" projectName="project name" projectId="PROJECT_ID" href="/app/rest/buildTypes/id:MY_BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID" webUrl="https://<serverUrl>/viewType.html?buildTypeId=MY_BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID">
    ...
    <features count="1">
        <feature id="BUILD_EXT_63" type="notifications">
            <properties count="11">
                <property name="branchFilter" value="+:&lt;default&gt;&#xA;+:br_name"/>
                <property name="buildFinishedFailure" value="true"/>
                <property name="buildFinishedSuccess" value="true"/>
                <property name="firstSuccessAfterFailure" value="true"/>
                <property name="notifier" value="jbSlackNotifier"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:addBranch" value="true"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:addBuildStatus" value="true"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:channel" value="#slack-channel-name"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:connection" value="PROJECT_EXT_10"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:maximumNumberOfChanges" value="10"/>
                <property name="plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:messageFormat" value="verbose"/>
            </properties>
        </feature>
    </features>
    ...
</buildType>
```

The property you are interested in is `plugin:notificator:jbSlackNotifier:channel`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I have tried to look for this section, but I saw that my notifications is set via Slack plugin to Teamcity. Is to get the plugin from an api?

Comment: @AmitHajaj could you edit your question with relevant screenshots to indicate how the configuration for Slack notification is done in your current TeamCity installation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697039/14697983

Comment: @AmitHajaj I've edited your original question, could you remove your answer for now? The additional details should just go into the original question, not as a new answer

Comment: @AmitHajaj is it an option for you to switch to Slack Notifier build feature (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/notifications.html)? Or is it a hard requirement to use the current set up?

Comment: I looked for it but this is not an option for me. My company works with an older version of TC..